# How to stop http response after failed responce

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, httprequest

I am using penguin PHP/MYSQL server app and My ionic 1 android app. App request a call every 30 seconds to server and it return some data, it is working perfectly when the server is ON. When server is OFF requests are made and getting the response as error,it is also ok but when i ON the server the responses will returned in bulk.

For Example - if there is a 10 calls (requests) in between server OFF to ON there will be 10 response after server ON.

Is there is a any way to stop the before made request response.

Please help me, Its creating lots of issues in app.

Comment: Is there something in the code that queues those request till the Server gets on? Because there should be no means to serve those requests when the server is off.

Comment: there is nothing, there is only request call every 30 seconds

Comment: when i see in console Log it gives the error when there is server OFF, after ON all the requested calls response will be responded at a time

Comment: when server is off,  if there's no response error code (i.e, 500) then those requests must be waiting for the server to respond, in such cases you can give a timeout function for the time it waits for response. I think it will do the job.

Comment: please any example

Comment: $http({
   method: "post",
   url: $localStorage.weburl,
   params: {
    action: "add"
   },
   data: {}
   }).then(function mySucces(response) {
   
   console.log("Response " + JSON.stringify(response));
   
   
   }, function myError(err) {
   $ionicLoading.hide();
   
   console.log("ERROR in server Response ===" + JSON.stringify(err));
  });

Comment: This is what i am using now, When i get error i want to cancel this response

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: did you try my answer which was posted yesterday? 
the other guy did the same with ionic framework.. Soppa ahe bhava!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to timeout the request after specific interval.

An example is illustrated bellow:

```
$http({
          method : "GET",
          url : "https://www.example.com/post",
          timeout: 1*35 * 1000   //35 secs just for safety, as it takes 30 secs for next request
      })
        .then(
            function mySuccess(response) {
               $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
            },
            function myError(response)   {
               $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
          });
```

If your server is down, The request will be timed out after it elapses the give interval, and it will show response error accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution in the ionic framework:

```
this.http.post('http://my.api', {your JSON data})
    .timeout(10000)
    .subscribe((Return_data) => {Do success Stuff}, (err) => {Do Fail Stuff})
```

Your request will stop in 10 seconds if it receives nothing.

You may need to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';` depending on your framework version.